# unable to setImage to UIButton in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, uibutton, xamarin

Unable to `setImage` for `UIButton`.

when set `backgroundColor` with Image its showing image which I want to set it "backButton.png"

When setImage to `UIButton` its not showing at all

```
 backButton.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("/Images/backButton.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

I want to setImage to `UIButton`.

// Below is code

```
UIButton backButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
backButton.Frame = new RectangleF (5, 5, 45, 30);
backButton.BackgroundColor =  UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("/Images/backButton.png"));
backButton.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("/Images/backButton.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
backButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, ea) => {
    this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you've to specify the `/Images/` folder. I think if you're picking from bundle there is no folder structure, all files resides in same directory

Comment: You are correct Inder... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the `Xamarin`. But the directory structure presented in xcode project is different than the actual (after app compiles).
All the files and resources resides in same directory called [main bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/mainBundle). 
And to access your resources you just ask for it from the main bundle. You don't have to specify the directory (in which resource resides) of you xcode project navigator.

You can read about more [directory structure here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you set images from Visual Studio from property box, it sets the image path like images\image1.png [when the image1.png file is in \Resources\Images folder.

But MAC doesn't support "\" path, you'll need to provide path with "/".

Answer (score 0):

I have come across recently against this very issue. I read that Apple recently enforced a change that all resources must reside within Resources directory when you create the project in Xamarin. You can create Image directory within the Resources directory and have your images there.

Now to read them back it is as simple as - if images are in Resources directory you can just use

```
UIImage.FromFile ("backButton.png")
```

But if your images are inside Resources/Images then use simply

```
UIImage.FromFile ("Images/backButton.png")
```

Note lack of backslash before the Images directory which now resides inside Resources directory.

This works for me. Sorry i don't recall the link that told me about the change and storage of Resources within the directory only but this fixed all my resource related issues.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted:

```
backButton.BackgroundColor =  UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromBundle("/Images/backButton.png"));
backButton.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("/Images/backButton.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

You use in one line `UIImage.FromFile` and in the other line `UIImage.FromBundle`. If I understood you correct the `"FromBundle"` version works, so try to use this one for the `SetImage` as well.